# Python covert x axis unit of gamma distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution, gamma-distribution

I have a gamma distribution with shape and scale parameter 2.126, 0.370.

You can plot it with following code:

```
shape, scale = 2.126, 0.370  # mean=4, std=2*sqrt(2)
s = np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000)

weights = np.ones_like(s)/float(len(s))
plt.hist(s, 30,weights=weights)
```

The parameters are originally used to describe the walking distance between home and a public transport node with unit `km`. Now I want to transfer the unit to `m`.

How could I keep the same shape, only with difference on the unit of `x Axis.` What should the new shape and scale parameters be?

To be more clear, I want the x axis scales to become 500, 1000, 1500 ... instead of 0.5, 1, 1.5 ...

Comment: Change the x axis labels or multiply the data by 1000?

Comment: Not so sure what do you mean, I wonder how could I get the new parameters.

Comment: Yes, I do. I suppose this requires a new combination of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @sciroccorics answer:

```
s = 1000*np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000)
fit_alpha, fit_loc, fit_beta=st.gamma.fit(data)
data=gamma.rvs(fit_alpha,loc=fit_loc,scale=fit_beta,size=5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your second line by:

```
s = 1000*np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 1000)
```

Comment: This could let me get the right histogram, but I wonder could I get the new shape and scale parameters without time 1000.

Comment: @Z Xie: no, because your gamma distribution is neither linear wrt to parameter `shape` nor to parameter `scale`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to fit the new histogram